# Restore Ubuntu configuration files / application on new install

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, installation

I have been asking myself  for a long time now and can't find any answer to it.

Every time I install Ubuntu on a new machine or reinstall an existing machine or create a VM, I need to go through installing all the utilities / application I use and adding macros/config to bashrc. Same with Vim I need to reinstall plugins I like and adding macros and config in vimrc.

My point here is, would it be possible to have an online service that store all that for you somewhere and whenever you install a new Ubuntu then you only need to install one client that would connect to the server and retrieve all information / config files and install them on the new machine so you effortlessly get an Ubuntu machine that have all the application and all the configuration you previously had.

I would simply like to know if anything like this exist or anything that would achieve the same purpose?

Comment: ansible, puppet and similar. Ansible is very good for this.

Comment: Ok that's great put is as answer and i'll mark it solve if that fits the bill but it seems to be. I'll have a look to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  What you're looking for are called `Configuration Management Tools`.
The most commonly used are Chef, Puppet, Ansible, Salt, and CFEngine.

They basically manage packages and configurations of software for a set of computers and allow you to create or update a computer with a predefined baseline.

You can find out more from the following:

http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/configuration-management-tools,2-920.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software